# iPhone SDK fonts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I have found a list of iOS 4.2 available fonts (link [here](http://www.michaelcritz.com/2010/04/02/fonts-for-ipad-iphone/)) but the list slightly differs from earlier versions of the SDK (link [here](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/)).

I can change the font in my code just fine, but what happens if I use a font available in the iOS 4.2 list which is not available on earlier SDK versions? For instance, HelveticaNeue-Italic appears in the iOS 4.2 SDK, but not ealier versions. So what happens when I use HelveticaNeue-Italic in my app and it is run on older iOS devices?

Many thanks,
Brett

PS...I've upgraded all my devices so I can't simply just try it ;-) So I thought I would see if anybody here has done this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases it won't show up at all.  For other cases, it will revert to the system font.  It depends on how you are displaying text within your application.

Answer (score 2):

Well actually, since iOS4 you are able to add in custom fonts into your applications!
Found this while searching around the internet, hopefully this helps.

http://www.daveallanson.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56:adding-custom-fonts-ios-4&catid=38:blog&Itemid=56

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fonts that are only available on 4.2, you should require 4.2, simple as that. What does it matter if it falls back to some standard font or doesn't show up at all if you can't even test this?